# I cant start server. (Symfony 5 server:run )

Tags: php, symfony, cmd, server, console

How can i start server?

My steps:

1- i installed composer

2- i created my project

```
C:\wamp\www> composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton symfony-kurs
```

3- then i tried to start the server

```
C:\wamp\www>symfony-kurs>php bin/console server:run
C:\wamp\www>symfony-kurs>php bin/console server:start
```

4- i realized there is a problem. Command "server:run" is not defined.

[server:run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCnzu.png)

[all server options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ6bf.png)

5-Then i tried install web server bundle with this code:

```
composer require symfony/web-server-bundle --dev
```

6- then i ve error. it is my output:

```
Could not find package symfony/web-server-bundle in a version matching 5.3.*
```

[InvalidArgumentException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Z5H.png)

7-Then i tired with `symfony server:run` and my output:

```
C:\wamp64\www\symfony-kurs>symfony server:run
'symfony' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

8- Then i wanted to create path for symfony and my output:

```
C:\>php -r "readfile('https://symfony.com/installer');"

Warning: readfile(https://symfony.com/installer): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in Command line code on line 1
```

Comment: Indeed, `web-server-bundle` doesn't exist for 5, it has been superceded by [Symfony server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html), and has to be installed in the system, not as a composer dependency.

Comment: You need the symfony CLI installed.  Follow the [directions](https://symfony.com/download) for your operating system.  There is actually a setup.exe for Windows.  Off topic but you will save yourself a bunch of trouble if you shift to a non Windows environment.  Consider using [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

Comment: you are right. that s my fault. i was doing it based on Symfony 4.

Comment: if you are working on windows , i suggest you this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71164888/how-to-install-symfony-cli-on-windows-10