# How to install symfony cli on windows 10?

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, command-line-interface, symfony-cli

I tried to install with scoop, tried with binary installation and it crashed. Everytime I run `symfony` command I always get `Warning: readfile(http://symfony.com/installer): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in Command line code on line 1`. Then I tried to install it on wsl, but I get same results. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Probably doing it the wrong way, check official documentation, use symfony cli

Comment: @AhmedGhiloubi I did everything according to documentation therefore I do not know where and what I did something wrong

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you install it using the recommended method, using Scoop tool

[Scoop official website](https://scoop.sh/)

Open powershell from start menu then paste this code to install it (I got it from scoop website)

```
Invoke-Expression (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://get.scoop.sh')
```

Then in powershell execute this command

```
scoop install symfony-cli
```

this is the current recommended method to install symfony cli on windows

After that check it by calling this command

```
symfony -v
```

If it doesn't work try closing powershell and open it again ( so It refreshs its variables ) the use the last command again

If this doesn't work the problem may be in your OS configuration or networking

Good luck

Comment: yes, or using the updated command `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you install it with power shell with the given steps

Step1 - Open Power shell and Run the command -

```
iwr -useb get.scoop.sh | iex
```

Note – If it asks for Some execution policy for powershell, run the following command and then try installing scoop.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Step 2 -

```
scoop install symfony-cli
```

Step 3 - Create Symfony Project -

```
symfony new newApp
```

Then

```
cd newApp
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to update to latest version using :

```
scoop update symfony-cli
```